# Objective-C: Get a result of a singleton-class method after finish executing the method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, dispatch-async

I have a singleton class that checks the login status of the app.

There's a method named `attemptToLogin` in the singleton class that makes an http request with parameters and returns with json data about the login status. (true or false)

Now in the main `TabBarViewController` i did the following:

```
@interface CustomTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation CustomTabBarController{
    LoginCheckSingleton *loginSingleton;
    dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myDomain.appName", NULL);
    loginSingleton = [LoginCheckSingleton sharedInstance];
    dispatch_sync(myCustomQueue, ^{
        [loginSingleton attemptToLogin];
    });
    if([loginSingleton.loginstat  isEqual: @"true"]){
        NSLog(@"Logged In");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Not Logged In");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToLoginView" sender:self];
    }
}
```

The `dispatch_sync` is not working properly here, i want to execute the function inside the dispatch_sync and get the results before executing the `if` statement under it. But the `if` statement is executed before the block inside the dispatch_sync has finished.

This is the `Singleton Class`:

```
#import "LoginCheckSingleton.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "SSKeychain.h"
#import "CustomTabBarController.h"
static LoginCheckSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
@interface LoginCheckSingleton (){
    NSString *serverURLString;
    NSURL *serverURL;
    NSString *userId;
    NSString *password;
    NSString *email;
    NSMutableArray *jsonContents;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    NSString *loggedInStatus;
    bool loggedInTF;

}

@end
@implementation LoginCheckSingleton{
}


+ (LoginCheckSingleton*) sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t _singletonPredicate;
    static LoginCheckSingleton *_singleton = nil;

    dispatch_once(&_singletonPredicate, ^{
        _singleton = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    });

    return _singleton;
}

+ (id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

-(void)attemptToLogin{
    // Retrieve credentials from Keychain
    userId = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.lazemni.iFresh"
                                      account:@"ifreshUserId"];
    password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.lazemni.iFresh"
                                      account:@"ifreshPassword"];
    email = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.lazemni.iFresh"
                                   account:@"ifreshEmail"];
    if(email == nil || password == nil){

        NSLog(@"empty username or password");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"not empty username or password");
        serverURLString = @"http://www.lazemni.com/demo/ifresh/api/login/";
        serverURLString = [serverURLString stringByAppendingString:email];
        serverURLString = [serverURLString stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
        serverURLString = [serverURLString stringByAppendingString:password];
        NSLog(@"%@",serverURLString);
        serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:serverURLString];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL];
        //AFNetworking asynchronous url request
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                             initWithRequest:request];

        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            jsonContents = [responseObject objectForKey:@"login"];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonContents);
            dictionary = [jsonContents objectAtIndex:0];
            loggedInStatus = [dictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
            if([loggedInStatus  isEqual: @"true"]){
                NSLog(@"Succefully loggedin!");
                [SSKeychain setPassword:[dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"] forService:@"com.lazemni.iFresh" account:@"ifreshUserId"];
                [SSKeychain setPassword:[dictionary objectForKey:@"email"] forService:@"com.lazemni.iFresh" account:@"ifreshEmail"];
                [SSKeychain setPassword:[dictionary objectForKey:@"password"] forService:@"com.lazemni.iFresh" account:@"ifreshPassword"];
                self.loginstat = @"true";
                loggedInTF = true;
            }else if([loggedInStatus  isEqual: @"false"]){
                NSLog(@"Wrong email/password combination!");
                self.loginstat = @"false";
                loggedInTF = false;
            }
        } failure:nil];
        [operation start];
    }
}


@end
```

I never understood how dispatch_sync really works, 
Any idea how to wait for the `[loginSingleton attemptToLogin];` to finish ?

Comment: What does attemptToLogin do? Why does it need to be in a dispatch closure at all? Why is not executed inline?

Comment: i added the singleton class with the called method, you can check it please

Comment: You need to create a callback for `attemptToLogin` method, after checking login finish in that method, you execute that callback. And in `CustomTabBarController` move `if` statement to that callback block of `attemptToLogin` method

Comment: @Gintama can you explain in code please :-)

Comment: @FadiObaji because i cannot format code in comment so i add code as an answer, you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)attemptToLogin:(void(^)(BOOL login))complete {
   ...
   [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        ....
       // After you get login status
       complete(your_login_status_here);
   }
}
```

And in `CustomTabBarController`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myDomain.appName", NULL);
    loginSingleton = [LoginCheckSingleton sharedInstance];

        [loginSingleton attemptToLogin:^(loginStatus){
               if([loginStatus  isEqual: @"true"]){
                   NSLog(@"Logged In");
               }else{
                    NSLog(@"Not Logged In");
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToLoginView" sender:self];
                    });
               }

        }];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! you saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

`attemptToLogin` is probably an asynchronous method. You want to write attemptToLogin in such a way that it gives you a callback when the HTTP Request finishes executing. You can do that by means of a completion block, or a delegate, or a notification.

If you wait for the request to finish, you'll end up blocking the main thread, which will freeze user interactions, leading to a terrible UX.

Comment: I added the singleton class, can you take a look at it please